# Edit Default rules from script in Beyond Compare

Tags: beyondcompare3

I have two files which I compare using Data Compare and I want to edit default rules from the script. I tried manually from BC interface and it worked, but I need to manipulate the rules within the script.

This is my script so far:

```
data-report layout:side-by-side &
  options:ignore-unimportant,display-mismatches,line-numbers &
  output-to:"%3" output-options:html-color "%1" "%2"
```

Any ideas how could I do that? I am using Beyond Compare 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare doesn't support editing Data Compare session settings with a scripting command.

As a workaround, open a graphical Data Compare session. Click the Rules toolbar button (referee icon). In the Columns tab, edit the column settings you want to use in your script. Change the dropdown at the bottom of the dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Also update session defaults** before you click OK. The modified default session settings will affect your script.

Comment: That was my only solution too, but I thought I can somehow do this with a scripting command. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a solution to this? I want to achieve the same.Pass unimportant command from script file.

Comment: No, it isn't possible to define unimportant text from a script or with a command line option. Changing the session defaults interactively is the only solution.